# How to make 4 channel "3.1 surround" WDM work with Winamp?

Tags: audio, drivers, sound-card, speakers

I'm using an external audio interface (Reloop Play). This supports 4 channels and ASIO. ASIO wise it works perfectly fine and is how i use it for music production or dj-ing (with Traktor).

For normal use it has WDM drivers that work quite reliably. Windows lets you configure the speaker setup to either stereo (2 channels) or 3.1 surround (4 channels) (and weirdly enough no Quadraphonic option which is the correct in this case as it should limit the range of the other 2 channels in 3.1 mode). If you use the "test" option in the speaker setup all 4 channels work in this mode. However after testing and searching a lot basically Winamp will only output to all channels in directsound output mode, but while it works with this audio interface when configured in stereo mode in 3.1 playback will just stay stuck since the decoder is unable to function. Enabling/disabling hardware acceleration nets no effect. It has to be configured in stereo mode else it won't play in directsound mode.

Which leads me to believe 3.1 support was never included in the decoder as the driver seems to function fine. So i'm thinking of the following solutions!?:
- Modify the driver to make it possible to be configured in Quadraphonic mode
- Use a virtual audio card that can take 2 channel stereo output from winamp and duplicated to the 2nd set of channels.

Kind regards,
St0RM53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution at least for Winamp only. WASAPI Maiko plug-in and set custom matrix. http://maiko.elementfx.com/